# Export Folder/Subfolder sizes across multiple servers from csv/txt file - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, diskspace

I am trying to get the size of folders and their subfolders in MB from multiple servers. I am expecting to get the result from multiple locations which are saved in text or CSV files. An example is below:

```
server1\C:\folder1
server2\D:\folder1
server3\E:\folder1
```

I have used the below script which works great but this only gives the result from disk size i.e. C:\ or D:\ and not the subfolder of C:\ or D:\

```
$DiskSizeReport = @()
$computers = get-content -path c:\temp\server_names.txt
$computers | ForEach {
$Disks = Get-WmiObject win32_logicaldisk -ComputerName $_ -Filter "Drivetype=3" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue |
Select-Object @{Label = "Server Name";Expression = {$_.SystemName}},
@{Label = "Drive Letter";Expression = {$_.DeviceID}},@{Label = "Total Capacity (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Size / 1GB)}},
@{Label = "Used Space (GB)";Expression = {(Round($_.Size /1GB,2)) - (Round($_.FreeSpace /1GB,2))}},
@{Label = "Free Space (GB)";Expression = {"{0:N1}" -f( $_.Freespace / 1GB ) }},@{Label = "Free Space (%)"; Expression = {"{0:P0}" -f ($_.freespace/$_.size) }}
$DiskSizeReport += $Disks
} 
$DiskSizeReport | Export-CSV "C:\DiskSizeReport.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Encoding UTF8`
```

This only gives me the result like:

```
"Server Name","Drive Letter","Total Capacity (GB)","Used Space (GB)","Free Space (GB)","Free Space (%)"
"Server1","C:","69.7",,"22.0","32%"
"Server1","E:","80.0",,"23.1","29%"
```

Please have a look and share your inputs. Thanks!

Comment: You want total disk and one folder or all folders ?

Comment: You're looking to do this to __all__ folders starting from root? Your report is going to be huge

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon thanks for formatting the post. It hurt me to read it like it was

Comment: I am going to bow out and hope someone else can answer. However, I think you want ```"{0} MB" -f ((Get-ChildItem C:\users\ -Recurse | Measure-Object -Property Length -Sum -ErrorAction Stop).Sum / 1MB)```
https://www.gngrninja.com/script-ninja/2016/5/24/powershell-calculating-folder-sizes

Comment: The key i think is ```Measure-Object```